# Set a $watch on a <SELECT> element in an Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

How do I set a $watch on the selectedvalue property of a SELECT element in an angular directive?  What is the syntax?  I have a partial directive below.  It doesn't blow up, but the watch never fires.

```
      link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {


        scope.$watch(elem.context.selectedOptions, function (selectedType) {
          console.log("nodup choice");
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a need here to put a watcher over an `select` dropdown to fire something on its value change. I'd suggest you to use `ng-change` event over that select box & have function over it. So that will get fire whenever input value gets changed.

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="changeFn()">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```